# Removing href with angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to remove href or ng-href attributes from an angular(v1.2.28) Directive

it works fine when the url doesn't have the string interpolation in it.

Could you please help me figure this out?

I just made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gfvewv5u/1/

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []);
angular.module('ui', ['ui.directives']);

angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('uiTool', 
  function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var controllerOptions, options;
        attrs.$set('href', null);
        element.removeAttr('href');
        element.text('iamfoo for what');
    }
  };
});

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.directives'])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.val = 1;
  });
```

And HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <a ui-tool href="/test/ts/{{val}}" >Link need to be removed</a>
        <a ui-tool href="/test/ts" >Link remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on my example the first link still got the href
while the 2nd link doens't

Comment: You have already defined the angular module angular.module('ui.directives', []);. So remove [] from angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('uiTool',

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to destroy the scope on the element that has a bound value. Angular keeps track of these bindings internally, and will reset the href.

```
element.scope().$destroy();
```

like so:

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    element.scope().$destroy();
    element.removeAttr('href');
    element.text('iamfoo for what');
}
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfvewv5u/4/)

Comment: If I destroy the scope binding won't work, amiright?

Comment: Hi @BrunoSantos it removes the binding if that’s what you mean, but that was the point of the question

Comment: Why does this plunker work without destroying the scope: https://plnkr.co/edit/FtHIxp29YURa1dZSJd1X?p=preview